# How to pass secret data to React component using react router link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm building a react app using redux and react router. I'm trying to send data to another component but don't want to pass it as params. is there any way I can transfer the data?

this is my component where the data is

```
/**
 * .app/components/helpers/Note.jsx
 */

// React import 
import React from 'react';

// React redux
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        notes: state.notes
    };
};

class ConnectingNote extends React.Component{   
    render(){
        const id = this.props.noteId;
        const note = this.props.notes.find( obj => obj.id == id); 
        return(
            <div className="section container"> 
                <h5 className="light">{note.title}</h5>
                <div className="divider"></div>
                <p className="flow-text">
                    {note.entry}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


const NoteItem = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectingNote);

export default NoteItem;
```

this is my route component

```
/**
 * .app/components/App.jsx
 */

// React import 
import React from 'react';

// helper components
import NavBar from '../helpers/NavBar.jsx';
import NoteItem from '../helpers/Note.jsx';
import Fab from '../helpers/FAB.jsx';

export default class Note extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            note: {}
        }
    }
    render(){
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        return(
            <div>
                <NavBar text='Home' link='/'/>
                <NoteItem noteId={id}/>
                <Fab note={this.state.note} icon='fa fa-pencil'
                    path={'/edit/' + id}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

this is my link to the route want to use the data

```
<Link className='btn-floating btn-large blue-grey'
                to={this.props.path}>
                   <i className={this.props.icon}></i>
               </Link>
```

please help. If there's anything needed to add to the question please tell me

Comment: why don't you save the data you want to your redux store and then pass it in as props where you need it? You're already using redux.

Comment: I don't know if its possible to collect and also send data in the same component in redux. Is it?

Comment: Of course, it is. Create an action, a reducer and then map the dispatch to props. You can also save to local storage if that works for this scenario.

Comment: Ok thank you so much